# automatically overwrite files in vb scripting

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

i am utilizing a vb script (written below) in order to create two .csv files out from an .xls one. Since this has to be utilized inside an iterative procedure via an algorithm I was wondering if there is a chance of overwriting the two generated files automatically. Right now I have to manually confirm every overwrite. The code is not mine since I am a real newbie in this, thank you so much

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the destination.    Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xlsx Destination.csv"
Wscript.Quit
End If
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))  
Dim WS1
Set WS1 = oBook.WorkSheets.item("Base Reactions")
WS1.Activate
oBook.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(1), 6
Dim WS2
Set WS2 = oBook.WorkSheets.item("Steel Sum - AISC 360-10")
WS2.Activate
oBook.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(2), 6
oBook.Close true
oExcel.Quit
```

Comment: that is not VB.NET code.  please use the correct tag: Vba, VBScript, excel-vba etc

Comment: If you use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` it will disable the alert that you're overwriting the file.

Answer (score 0):

From Object Browser (Alt + F11, F2, search for SaveAs)

```
Sub SaveAs([Filename], [FileFormat], [Password], [WriteResPassword], [ReadOnlyRecommended], [CreateBackup], [AccessMode As XlSaveAsAccessMode = xlNoChange], [ConflictResolution], [AddToMru], [TextCodepage], [TextVisualLayout], [Local])
    Member of Excel.Workbook
```

Press F1 for Help

```
ConflictResolution   Optional XlSaveConflictResolution.
```

XlSaveConflictResolution can be one of these XlSaveConflictResolution constants.

```
xlUserResolution  (display the conflict-resolution dialog box) 
xlLocalSessionChanges (automatically accept the local user's changes) 
xlOtherSessionChanges  (accept other changes instead of the local user's changes)
```

If this argument is omitted, the conflict-resolution dialog box is displayed.